# Simple constexpr function failed to compile with GCC (clang is OK)

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, template-meta-programming, constexpr

The following code [does not compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=36d9c1ef29c4cf8e) with GCC 5.2 (C++14). It [does compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=1a32589a7b3695c3) with clang 3.6 (C++14). (original code can be found [here](https://github.com/Lingxi-Li/Happy_Hacking_CXX/blob/master/hhxx/aggregate_wrapper.hpp))

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
class aggregate_wrapper;

template <typename T, std::size_t n>
class aggregate_wrapper<T[n]> {
public:
  using array = T[n];

  template <typename... Ts, typename = decltype(array{std::declval<Ts>()...})>
  aggregate_wrapper(Ts&&... xs)
      : arr_{std::forward<Ts>(xs)...} {
    // nop
  }

  aggregate_wrapper(const array& arr) {
    std::copy(arr, arr + n, arr_);
  }
  aggregate_wrapper(array&& arr) {
    std::move(arr, arr + n, arr_);
  }

  operator T* () {
    return arr_;
  }
  operator const T* () const {
    return arr_;
  }

  constexpr std::size_t size() const {
    return n;
  }

private:
  array arr_;
};

int main() {
  aggregate_wrapper<int[3]> arr;
  static_assert(arr.size() == 3, "");
}
```

The error message produced is

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:44:3: error: non-constant condition for static assertion
   static_assert(arr.size() == 3, "");
   ^
main.cpp:44:25: error: call to non-constexpr function 'constexpr std::size_t aggregate_wrapper<T [n]>::size() const [with T = int; long unsigned int n = 3ul; std::size_t = long unsigned int]'
   static_assert(arr.size() == 3, "");
                         ^
main.cpp:34:25: note: 'constexpr std::size_t aggregate_wrapper<T [n]>::size() const [with T = int; long unsigned int n = 3ul; std::size_t = long unsigned int]' is not usable as a constexpr function because:
   constexpr std::size_t size() const {
                         ^
main.cpp:34:25: error: enclosing class of constexpr non-static member function 'constexpr std::size_t aggregate_wrapper<T [n]>::size() const [with T = int; long unsigned int n = 3ul; std::size_t = long unsigned int]' is not a literal type
main.cpp:10:7: note: 'aggregate_wrapper<int [3]>' is not literal because:
 class aggregate_wrapper<T[n]> {
       ^
main.cpp:10:7: note:   'aggregate_wrapper<int [3]>' is not an aggregate, does not have a trivial default constructor, and has no constexpr constructor that is not a copy or move constructor
```

Any ideas? Should the code compile according to the standard?

Comment: Constructors are not marked `constexpr`. neither `arr`.

Comment: @Jarod42 So, basically, clang is not conforming here?

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const. Enjoy.

Comment: @Lingxi : The code is definitely ill-formed; constexpr member functions are illegal on non-literal types. However, this may be a case where no diagnostic is required.

Comment: @ildjarn That restriction was removed by [CWG1684](http://wg21.link/cwg1684)

Comment: @T.C. : Ah, news to me; thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you could just make your existing variadic constructor serve as your `constexpr` constructor to perform the default construction:

```
template <typename... Ts, typename = decltype(array{std::declval<Ts>()...})>
constexpr                      // <---- ADD THIS
aggregate_wrapper(Ts&&... xs)
   : arr_{std::forward<Ts>(xs)...} {
   // nop
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for g++ to get it compiled you will need to add a default constructor:

```
aggregate_wrapper() = default;
```

please see it in action at: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df1ac057960bebc7

I have the feeling that clang under the hood added it, but I am not 100% sure ...

Comment: Making `size()` a static member seems a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

GCC is wrong. Its diagnostic, in part, says:

```
main.cpp:34:25: note: '<...>' is not usable as a constexpr function because:
main.cpp:34:25: error: enclosing class of constexpr non-static member function '<...>' is not a literal type
```

... but there is no such rule. See [dcl.constexpr]/3 for the list of constraints that apply here.

You can work around the bogus GCC diagnostic by adding a dummy `constexpr` constructor (it's fine for that constructor to be private and/or deleted if you don't want any of your real constructors to be `constexpr`) or by making `size` be `static`.